# How To Create a Horizontal Menubar With Icons in Android

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I am new to android UI development. I want to have a simple clean layout.

[Here is an image of what I am trying to achieve.](https://lh6.ggpht.com/bYyOlpCJCiWzd4goBnzRGs14ziwdKd16VTHkku3sMiFJuXcNPmzcMZ_l90InWq2NnLRW=h900)

What would be the best way to structure the white navigation bar at the bottom of the screen.

I have tried using listview and inflated menu from the android api but they dont seem to give me the desired effect.

At present I have a number of images in a table row, but I am not sure if that is best practice.

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I would use a RelativeLayout as your parent view and a child LinearLayout with horizontal orientation for your navigation bar. A RelativeLayout is great for positioning views on screen and a LinearLayout works very well for holding a single row of view elements.

Information on those:

LinearLayout: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html
RelativeLayout: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html